# Rails assign one field value to another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

folks! I'm using Ruby On Rails 4.2.1, and PostgreSQL for the database.

I have a database table with `:player1` and `:player2` fields in it.

How can I assign one of these fields value to the third field, let's say `:result` field?

e.g.

```
player1 == "Paul"
player2 == "Tom"
result == "Paul" # Here comes one of the previous two field's value
```

And what is the best way to achieve this? I'm not very good at programming in Ruby (still learning).

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your question, could you specify what code you're talking about? Btw, I can update question with example of my own code I'm using in my app.

Comment: Yes, please do that - it'll help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a before save in your **model** where you can assign your first or second field value to the third field.

```
before_save :assign_value
```

Comment: `before_filter` in model?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly. But it seems like you have:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

> Now you are asking how can I have `result = a`?

You can just do:

```
result = a
```

to assign `result` the value of a.

The same thing you can do with your database fields.

```
player1 == "Paul"
player2 == "Tom"
```

You can just do:

```
self.result = self.player1
# then save the model instance
```

This will assign the same value of `player1` field to your `result` field of this model instance.